# Can NEXUS be used when entering the US via the CBX Bridge in Tijuana, Mexico?

Tags: airports

I am flying into Tijuana International Airport (TIJ) and will use the CBX skywalk bridge to enter the United States at San Diego. Does CBX participate in the NEXUS program to speed the entry process?

Answer (score 11):

CBX has [a SENTRI lane](https://www.crossborderxpress.com/faq).

> CBX participates in the Global Entry, and Sentri programs.

NEXUS members are [allowed to use SENTRI lanes](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/227/~/nexus---general-information).

> They can also use their card in dedicated SENTRI lanes along the U.S.-Mexico border and can use, at no charge, the Global Entry Program.

So I would say the answer is yes.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one. A "SENTRI lane" is a lane with an RFID reader for cars at a southern border crossing (like a "NEXUS lane" at the northern border); I don't think this is relevant at CBX. What would be relevant are Global Entry machines, but CBX/TIJ isn't on [the list of airports that have them](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/locations). I'm hence not sure what facility is implied by "participates in ...".

Comment: @Dennis There are indeed Global Entry kiosks at CBX, but they're rather different, and the only real benefit they give is to be able to skip the line. You still have to talk to a CBP officer. See also [this walkthrough of CBX in both directions](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2016/06/12/cbx-san-diego-tijuana/). I haven't yet figured out how one is supposed to use SENTRI at CBX.