# CBX crossing TIJUANA - SAN DIEGO

Tags: usa, international-travel, mexico, sentri

Can I use my Sentri card at the CBX entry port San Diego coming back from Mexico?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

https://www.crossborderxpress.com/en/faq

> Does the Trusted traveler program apply in CBX?
>
> Yes. The trusted traveler program applies to CBX, including Global Entry and Sentri.

See also [Can NEXUS be used when entering the US via the CBX Bridge in Tijuana, Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78078/can-nexus-be-used-when-entering-the-us-via-the-cbx-bridge-in-tijuana-mexico/78081#78081)